# Which permissions are needed to fetch metrics from arango?

Tags: arangodb

I want to fetch arangodb metrics with prometheus.
Since I enabled authertication this has to be done with an user and password.

What are the required permissions needed for this?

This works so far:

```
arangosh
const users = require('@arangodb/users');
users.save('prometheus', 'supersecure')
users.grantDatabase("prometheus", "_system", "ro")
users.grantCollection("prometheus", "_system", "*", "none")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the last command is not necessary. These are my steps:

- Create an user `prometheus` which read-only access to `_system` as you suggest
- Create an access token

  ```
  require('@arangodb/crypto').jwtEncode(
    "secret_token", {
      "preferred_username": "prometheus", 
      "allowed_paths": ["/_admin/metrics"], 
      "iss": "arangodb", 
      "exp": Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 31536000 }, 
    "HS256");
  ```

  where `secret_token` is the super-user token and `31536000` is the time to live in seconds in this case roughly a year.

This token will grant access to the `/_admin/metrics` API like so:

```
curl -H"Authorization: bearer $TOKEN" https://instance-ip:port/_admin/metrics
```